# How to convert a byte to a char, e.g. 1 -> '1'?

Tags: c#, char, byte

How to convert a byte to a char? I don't mean an ASCII representation.
I have a variable of type `byte` and want it as a character.

I want just following conversions from byte to char:
0 ->'0'
1 ->'1'
2 ->'2'
3 ->'3'
4 ->'4'
5 ->'5'
6 ->'6'
7 ->'7'
8 ->'8'
9 ->'9'

`(char)1` and `Convert.ToChar(1)` do not work. They result in `''` because they think `1` is the ASCII code.

Comment: @TuTran Yes. In my case the byte variable is just a single digit between 0 and 9.

Comment: A variation of @Cicada's solution: `byteVariable.ToString().Single()` – using `System.Linq`; will throw an exception if variable exceeds `9`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks, I will use `Single()` - just to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the number `.ToString();`

```
one.ToString(); // one.ToString()[0] - first char -'1'
two.ToString(); // two.ToString()[0] - first char -'2'
```

**Note that you can't really convert a `byte` to a `char`**
 `char` is one char while byte can even three digits value!

---

If you want to use `LINQ` and you're sure the byte won't exceed one digit(10+) you can use this:

```
number.ToString().Single();
```

Comment: I can't believe there are so many convoluted answers on this, and they're getting higher scores than this one!

Comment: @gdoron Comment to your note: It is ok in my case because I have only one-digit numbers. So **in my case** it is ok to write: `one.ToString()[0]` or @JeppeStigNielsen's hint `one.ToString().Single()`.

Comment: A `byte` (`System.Byte`) can't have negative values. That's an `sbyte`.

Answer (score 5):

Use this for conversion.

```
(char)(mybyte + 48);
```

where `mybyte` = 0 or 1 and so

**OR**

```
Convert.ToChar(1 + 48); // specific case for 1
```

While others have given solution i'll tell you why your `(char)1` and `Convert.ToChar(1)` is not working.

When your convert byte 1 to char it takes that `1` as an `ASCII` value.

**Now `ASCII of 1 != 1`.**

Add 48 in it because   ASCII of 1  == 1 + 48`. Similar cases for 0, 2 and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Simply using `variable.ToString()` should be enough. If you want to get fancy, add the ASCII code of `0` to the variable before converting:

```
Convert.ToChar(variable + Convert.ToByte('0'));
```

Comment: How can you convert a byte to a char? what about 10+ values?

Comment: @gdoron: By taking the value of the byte as the ordinal of the character in the BMP of course. The question clearly states that we 're not interested in 10+ values though.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have variable `byte x;`
Just use `(char)(x + '0')`

Comment: `x` is a `byte`. and as you comments, what will happen when x i bigger than 9? you will get some ascii code instead.

Comment: @gdoron: Sorry for using int, but the author said it just 0 to 9, so your mention case will not occur

Answer (score 2):

Use Convert.ToString() to perform this.

Comment: Why `convert.ToString()` and not just `.Tostring()`... `:)`

Comment: How can a `byte` be `null`? it's a `struct`. From the **MSDN** _"This implementation is identical to Byte.ToString()."_ [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b4d9sx5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the result must be a Char (and not a string), an obvious and simple solution is:

```cs
"0123456789"[yourByte]
```

This produces a Char directly.