# how to convert c++ char read using "Marshal.ReadByte" to c# char?

Tags: c#

In c++ I have regular `char` (something like 'J' '0' etc.). I read it in c# using `Marshal.ReadByte` method. So now in c# I have byte. How can I convert this byte to char? So i want to convert 'J' in c++ to 'J' in c#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649440/how-to-convert-a-byte-to-a-char-e-g-1-1

Comment: i don't want to convert 1 to '1'. i want to convert 1 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the source `char` is using ASCII or Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1), in C# you'd do `char ch = (char)Marshal.ReadByte(...);`.

This works because the ASCII and Latin-1 encodings are subsets of Unicode. A .NET `char` is a UTF-16 code unit, which will fit each of these fine with just a cast.

If you think you'll deal with other source encodings, a better option may be to use `Encoding.GetString()` on a byte array. Keep in mind that some encodings require multiple units to encode a single code point (UTF-8, EUC-JP, Shift-JIS, etc.), so a single `char` may not be enough.

Comment: You can't implicitly convert `byte` to `char` (but you can do it explicitly).

Comment: probably I should add cast but I was thinking probaly more robust and elegant solution exist...

Comment: @javapowered More robust in what way? I doubt you will need to handle EBCDIC. And if you're worried about encodings like UTF-8, then that's not 1-to-1 to C# `char`s, you do need to use something like `Encoding.GetString()` on the whole string, as Cory proposed. And I think cast *is* the most elegant solution to “I have variable of type X and want to convert it to type Y”.

Comment: i only need it to work. always. will cast always work? because I'm casting 1-byte variable to 2-byte variable, i'm completely not sure how this will be handled.

Comment: Casting will always work _if the source encoding is ASCII_. ASCII (chars 0 to 127) maps directly to Unicode and will losslessly convert to a .NET `char` (which represents a UTF-16 code unit) every time.